# HTACCESS does not work when file with same name exists

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have a little problem which might be easy to solve, but I don't exactly know how. I have the following folder structure:

- main website
  -- content for website
  -- more content
  --- subfolder called cms
  --- index.php
  --- content.php (and of course more)

the index.php file is as following:

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    require_once($_GET['page'].'.php');
}
```

My HTACCESS for the subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried to echo my $_GET['page'] variable in index.php and whenever I enter something like this: `www.domain.com/cms/r` it gives me `$_GET['page'] = r` which is fine. However, if the $_GET variable exists as a file, I get a 404 error: `www.domain.com/cms/content`, which should just display my content.php file.

What exactly am I doing wrong? All help appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

it seems I can get my `$_GET` working, but it ignores if a file with the name of the `$_GET` exists. www.domain.com/fluidify/content won't work because there is a file named content.php in the folder, however www.domain.com/fluidify/testget gives met `testget` as output.

Comment: so if file not exist you want it to pass to index.php?

Comment: No I want the file to be included in index.php, but when the file exists, it does not work. I am looking if i can find any problems in the files themselves, but this is the only project not working out of hundreds... only difference is that this is once again another server/hosting

Comment: The problem lays somewhere else...the subdirectory does not remember sessions, which I need for the secutiry to load the files... Why in the name a server does not hold `$_SESSION`? How can i solve this?

Comment: The problem lays somewhere else related to this, but gotta explain it differently...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have SEO-friendly URLs then you should use something like this - this will redirect everything to your routing script no matter if the URL matches an existing file or not.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Almost! The problem is that all my stylesheets and images are rewritten as well - at least, they are not working anymore and give me errors - .

Comment: I edited my question a bit for more clarity on what's happening right now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am really confused - first you say that you can not reach `index.php` if the requested file exists, now you say that you are reaching `index.php` even if the requested file exists. So which one of the 2 do you want to achieve ? Usually you do not keep your static assets in the same folder as your scripts. It would be easier with `www.site.com/index.html`, `www.site.com/static/js/jquery.js`, `www.site.com/static/css/main.css`, `www.site.com/cms/seo-friendly-url`